# Nginx shows 403 page on all php errors

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, php-5.6

I have Amazon ec2 server running nginx + php-fpm-5.6

It opens php pages correctly when there are no errors, but if any kind of error occurs (php error or exception) it always displays the same page (`/test.php` is the requested url):

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /test.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried changing php "display_errors" option.

When I enable it all scripts begin to show 403 page. In php error log I see a warning message that I should define default timezone. When I define it with 
`date_default_timezone_set(...);` in my scripts 403 error goes and appears only when a script has some mistake or if I write `throw new Exception();` for example.

How can I bring back normal error messages with details of an error and place in file where it has occured?

Upd. My nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    client_max_body_size 200m;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/admin.xuno.com.au.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/admin.xuno.com.au.error.log;

    location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
    }
}
```

Main nginx.conf

```
user dev-user;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question and add an `nginx` configuration file?

Comment: @RichardSmith: I've added it.

Comment: I can't replicate the 403. Are you sure that the `/var/www/html` is readable by user dev-user? I have noticed two minor issues (but not related), location regex should be `\.php$` (missing backslash) and you need `try_files $uri =404;` inside same location to ensure script file exists.

Comment: At my local machine I have same config and everything works well too. I've fixed your notices but nothing's changed. The folder and all it's content belong to dev-user:dev-user.